# countability vs uncountability of a specific set

Tags: real-analysis

The problem which i came over sounds like that:
 Let $A$ be a set with one (finite) accumulation point $x_0$ . If there are infinite many elements both greater and smaller than $x_0$ and if $x_0{\notin}$A, prove that we can choose  two convergent disjunct monotone sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ so that there exists $n$  such that $x_n=x$ or $y_n=x$ , for every  $x\in A$. 
 I observed that if $a,b >x_0$ or if $a,b<x_0$ , then $(a,b)\cap A$ has a finite number of elemnts. I will refer to this as ($*$).
 1) DOES ($*$) assures that A is countable? - I can t really prove this fact, although i feel it is true. 
2)Working on only one side, can we just take $a,b\rightarrow x_0$, $a,b<x_0$ and on the base of ($*$) arrange every element in  $(a,b)\cap A$ as an increasing sequence and then take a>b and continue the process? would not it be considered as a countable reunion of countable sets? if it is considered so, how do we prove that the number of reunions is countable? Is defining a function  which associates a rational number to every interval a correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it does. Indeed, $\mathbb{R}-\{x_0\}=\bigcup_{x_0<q<s\vee q<s<x_0;\ q,s\in\mathbb{Q}}(q,s)$.
   Therefore $A=\bigcup_{x_0<q<s\vee q<s<x_0;\ q,s\in\mathbb{Q}}A\cap(q,s)$, which is a countable union of finite sets.
2. Well... I guess you use a convention in which $\mathbb{Z}$ has $-\infty$ as an "accumulation point", so from now on I'll assume $-\infty<\inf(A)\leq\sup(A)<+\infty$ (the thesis would be false otherwise).
   Even so, I'm under the impression that the approaches you suggested, though they can probably prove countability, are missing a point: countability alone is not enough, because $\mathbb{Q}\cap[x_0-1,x_0+1]$ is countable, but far from what you want. *Obviously*, it does fail to have finite intersection with every open interval, for this fact is sufficient to solve the exercise.
   If I may, though not strictly required, I'd assume what you proved to propose a complete solution that I consider easier.

   Let's work on $C:=A\cap(-\infty,x_0)=A\cap[\inf(A),x_0)\neq\emptyset$; let $m:=\inf(A)$

   Let $\{h_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ a strictly growing sequence such that $h_0=m,\ \sup_nh_n=x_0$. $C=\bigcup_{n=0}^{+\infty}A\cap[h_n,h_{n+1})$, that is a disjoint union of finite sets, since $A\cap[h_n,h_{n+1})\subseteq A\cap(h_n-12,h_{n+1})$.

   Now the existence of a strictly-growing surjective function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow C$ is easily shown (you *need* a construction like that disjoint union)

   Indulging into details, let 
   $$s_m:=\sum_{k=0}^m\#(A\cap[h_m,h_{m+1}));\\
   t_n:=\max\{m\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ s_m<n\};\\
   f(n):=(n-s_{t_n})\text{-th lowest element of }C\cap[h_{t_n},h_{t_{n+1}})$$

   Where $\#$ is the cardinality of a set.

   $x_n:=f(n)$ can be proven to be a well-defined (because $\#C=\aleph_0$) strictly growing function surjective on $C$.